# Implement salt-minion log rotate on Windows

Tags: logging, salt-stack, log-rotation

My aim is to implement log rotation for salt-minion installed on Windows. 
It seems - there is no standard way to reach that: issues [34265](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/34265) and [26195](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/26195) on their GitHub are still alive.

I thought about some sort of win-task + a bit of scripting, but I don't want to unexpectedly stop salt-minion service: it might execute important tasks that should not be interrupted.

Maybe someone has a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you add codes you worked with so far ?

Comment: Well, I'm quite familiar with C#, powershell and python

Comment: No I mean for implementing what you want. Have you tried anything? Please add it to your question as a starting point. If you haven't please try and code an script then post it here. Questions in SO should have source code in them!

Comment: Thank you, Ehsan. As far as I can see it, the question is not about code, but the way of solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Loren Gordon for [reply](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/xlI7GFAHFDI) and Sergey Kizunov for [implementation](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/pull/37200), we've got changeset merged to develop. I hope it would be in release soon.